# Doubts about the different states of the Japanese tilde '~' displayed in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I found that the adjacent letters of the Japanese tilde are small if they are Chinese characters, and large if they are kana.
I would like to ask the seniors, is this a feature of the language, or a bug of vscode? See below

```
～つ
～着
～羽
～番
～足
～度
～キロ（メートル）
```

[image: When adjacent to a pseudonym, it becomes larger]

The search function, can confirm, is the same character, so I'm confused.
Moreover, my file encoding is UTF-8, there should be no strange character set errors.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Mac (all FULLWIDTH TILDE characters are wide). Is this Windows? I see at least one other person making that complaint (regarding Discord on Windows, which also uses Electron for rendering). https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/q4sem3/incorrect_display_of_fullwidth_tilde/  I expect this is an Electron quirk; you may want to ask at https://github.com/electron/electron if no one knows here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was very valuable to me